# How to determine a unified hight for several ui-btn in ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How can I determine a unified hight for several ui-btn in ul?

For example in the following code:

```
<div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
            <ul class="ui-grid-d ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
                <li class="ui-block-a ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="one" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true"><a href="#one" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Overview</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-b ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="two" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#two" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Products</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-c ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="recent" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#recent" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Employees</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-d ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="recent" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false"><a href="#recent" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4">Followers</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-e ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="activity" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false"><a href="#activity" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5">Recent activities</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I don't don't want to determine for each `<li>`/`<a>` , just determine it once for all the buttons

Comment: Can you be more clear about your question?

Comment: I want to determine just one time height style for all the ui-btn in the ul

Comment: .ui-btn{height:100px}; so something like this css <---

Comment: I have more ui-btns in other navbar. I have to be specific

Comment: Please improve your question. As it stands now, it is likely to be closed sooner than later. Explain clearly what you want to do. Determine width is **not** same as setting width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your navbar a id like this:

```
<div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" id="navbar1" role="navigation">
```

And then just use this css code:

```
#navbar .ui-btn{height:100px};
```

This only changes the height from this navbar and doesnt affect the others.